# Getting the last child of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example i have a for loop here which will generate some number lay inside a div

```
var countProfile = 0;
var tablehtml = "";
  for (var i=0; i <10; i++){

    tablehtml = tablehtml　+ '<div class="DataCount">'+countProfile+'</div>'

    countProfile++; 
   };

  $("#somewhere").html(tablehtml);
```

And I am trying to grab the last child for another method to use, I tried to use `:last-child()` but it doesn't works in my application, am i doing it wrong?

```
var dataCounting = $(".DataCount:last-child").html();
console.log(dataCounting);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`:last-child`](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)** selects last one in their parents which can be more than one if they are in different parent, instead try **[`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/)** or **[`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)**

```
$(".DataCount").last().html();
```

---

Or if there is only one parent and which contains different types of element then  sometimes **[`:last-child`](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)** will not work as you expected ( for more info : [The Difference Between :nth-child and :nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/) ) so in that case use **[`:last-of-type`](https://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/)** instead.

```
$(".DataCount:last-of-type").html();
```

Comment: I am using .last(), but it only works during the first time the user click on it, and when the click on it again it returns undefine

Comment: it's just my own bug, it's fixed

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `:last` selector...

`$(".DataCount:last").html();`

API documentation here https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/